# Is there a conflict between ReactJS Firebase and Firebase Functions?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I had a working ReactJS app that was using Firebase.

I am following [Robin Wieruch's React/Redux/Firebase Tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial).

I then added Firebase functions, and now my app fails to start. The error I get is, for example, app.database() is not a function when instantiating the Firebase Class.

Here is a brief snippet:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/storage'

import config from './config'

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    
    app.initializeApp(config);

    /* Helper */

    this.serverValue = app.database.ServerValue;
    this.emailAuthProvider = app.auth.EmailAuthProvider;

    /* Firebase APIs */

    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.database();
}
```

I have the app working in the old repository without functions, so the only thing I can figure is that adding Firebase functions has introduced some conflict.

The directory structure is:

```
src/
node_modules/
functions/
functions/node_modules/
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean Firebase cloud functions? Is there a reason you've installed them in the same directory as your React app? That seems like asking for trouble in terms of Node correctly resolving the modules.

Comment: I'm guessing you're right. I had installed them on a previous project and never ran into any issues. On the other hand, I didn't use the Firebase class instantiation. Do you know if it's complicated to uninstall?

Comment: Shouldn't be. Move the code you need, delete your `node_modules` directories and run `npm` or `yarn` install again

Comment: Thanks. I removed the functions folder, but still run into the issue. I think I see the issue. When I console.log app after app.initialize(), I see analytics, auth, and others, but no database and firestore. Do you know how I add those features?

Comment: I don't know why database isn't there. Firestore isn't there because you aren't importing it.

Comment: Ok, this sounds ridiculous, but this is what worked. I was using Yarn to install my npm modules. I did an rm -rf and used npm to install, and it worked. Does that make sense?

Comment: NPM and Yarn *should* lead to the same resolutions. But, doing a `rm -rf` and reinstall is always a good idea when encountering these issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Only a guess... Is it possible that you need to import functions, and `this.functions = app.functions()` as you have with db and auth?

Comment: Hmm, that's worth a shot, but the issue is that I'm getting an error that says app.database() is not a function.